# Rails mysql - 2 counts in 1 query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, select, count

I've checked out a few other answers but haven't been able to apply them to my query.  My chores, and complete counts are conflicting with each other.  I've tried SUM but that did not work.  Both counts work on their own if I remove the reference to the other count and corresponding table as well.

```
    @bays = Bay.
    select('COUNT(comp.id) as complete_count, COUNT(ch.count) as chore_count, comp.*, s.*, t.*, u.*, u.number as unit_number, b.*').
    from('bays b').
    joins('LEFT JOIN units u ON u.bay_id = b.id AND u.bay_id is not null').
    joins('LEFT JOIN sections s ON u.id = s.unit_id').
    joins('LEFT JOIN trades t ON s.trade_id = t.id AND t.production = 1').
    joins('LEFT JOIN completions comp ON t.id = comp.trade_id AND comp.unit_id = u.id').
    joins('LEFT JOIN chores ch ON t.id = ch.trade_id').
    joins('LEFT JOIN deficiencies d ON d.trade_id = t.id AND d.unit_id = u.id AND d.closed = 0').
    order("u.id, t.position").
    group("b.id, u.id, s.id, ch.id").
    group_by{|u| [u.id, u.number, u.unit_number]}
```

Comment: When you say your chores and complete counts are conflicting each other, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: When I take out the completions join, and the completions count, the the chores count is fine.  Otherwise the chores count matches the compeletion count.  The two table are very similar, the both have trade_id and unit_id

Comment: Try adding `distinct` in your count clauses then.

Comment: THANKS!  If you put in an answer I'll check it.  What is that doing exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count the distinct values of your two tables' columns:

```
@bays = Bay.
select('COUNT(DISTINCT comp.id) as complete_count, COUNT(DISTINCT ch.count) as chore_count, comp.*, s.*, t.*, u.*, u.number as unit_number, b.*').
from('bays b').
joins('LEFT JOIN units u ON u.bay_id = b.id AND u.bay_id is not null').
joins('LEFT JOIN sections s ON u.id = s.unit_id').
joins('LEFT JOIN trades t ON s.trade_id = t.id AND t.production = 1').
joins('LEFT JOIN completions comp ON t.id = comp.trade_id AND comp.unit_id = u.id').
joins('LEFT JOIN chores ch ON t.id = ch.trade_id').
joins('LEFT JOIN deficiencies d ON d.trade_id = t.id AND d.unit_id = u.id AND d.closed = 0').
order("u.id, t.position").
group("b.id, u.id, s.id, ch.id").
group_by{|u| [u.id, u.number, u.unit_number]}
```

Basically, `COUNT` will count every non-null value. The way you join the tables, if one table has more matching records than another one, it forces MySQL to fill in the holes of the 'smaller' table with duplicate values. By adding `DISTINCT`, your count will ignore those values, thus giving you the right number.